# MVC 3 Date Picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently trying to create a page which needs two date pickers in order to get the date time. I have to use another viewmodel to show person detail,so the system time model could not be used on the same page?

Is there anyont got idea about how to solve this problem?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Add your 2 date time properties to your viewmodel.

```
public DateTime MyDate1{ get; set; }
public DateTime MyDate2{ get; set; }
```

In your view add a class to your input fields

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate1,  new{ Class = "datepicker" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate2,  new{ Class = "datepicker" })
```

Use JQuery's date picker.   http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```